# C++ Template class member on a template function

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, metaprogramming

I have a thread pool that should accept any std::packaged_task and give a future.

```
template<typename RetType>
template<typename Args...>
std::future<RetType> submitWork(std::packaged_task<RetType(Args...)>&& callableWork>);
```

As you can see the packaged_task is templated. Now my thread pool uses a lockless queue as a member of the class

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
private:
    llQueue<boost::variant<???>> workQueue;
}
```

I want the work queue to be a variant of the types that submitWork gets called by. Ex: this code

```
bool runByPool(int var)
{
     //do stuff
}

int runAlso(char c)
{
    //do other stuff
}

ThreadPool pool; // 4 worker threads
pool.submitWork<bool(int)>(std::bind(runByPool, 1));
pool.submitWork<int<c>>(std::bind(runAlso, 'a'));
```

Gives the following type to workQueue at compilation:

```
llQueue<boost::variant<std::packaged_task<bool(int)>,
                       std::packaged_task<int(c)>
                      >
        >
```

How do i make the member of the class use the types of the templated submitWork? I want to force the llQueue to only hold std::packaged_task's and i used a variant so that i can avoid heap allocation since this need to be highly, highly performant.

I would like to avoid heap allocations and i need the same pool to be able to execute any work with any return type or parameter type

Comment: Remove the `&&` from your packaged task signature btw.  It does not do what you think it does there.

Comment: thanks can you explain why that doesn't perfect forward?

Comment: Because perfect forward is a bad term for forwarding references.  There is nothing to "forward" when pattern matching some other template's template argments, and when not pattern matching forwarding references do not behave intuitively to most.

Comment: Oh neat, i hadn't considered thinking of it as pattern matching, it was more of an expanding tree being filled on instantiation with rules on when things collapse in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most the code you posted does not compile.

```
pool.submitWork<bool(int)>(std::bind(runByPool, 1));
```

the signature of `std::bind(runByPool, 1)` is `bool()` not `bool(int)`.  The same error is in your other example, well, ignoring the other syntax errors there.

```
std::future<RetType> submitWork(std::packaged_task<RetType&&(Args&&...)&& callableWork>);
```

this signature is insanity.  It should be;

```
std::future<RetType> submitWork(std::packaged_task<RetType(Args...)> callableWork);
```

next, it makes almost no sense to take work that still needs args of a non-uniform type.  Which is reflected in your examples.

In fact, taking a packaged task here is pointless.

```
std::future<RetType> submitWork(std::function<RetType()> callableWork>);
```

makes more sense.  You take an operation returning a T, and return a future T.

```
llQueue<boost::variant<???>> workQueue;
```

there is no need for a variant here.  You want a queue of tasks you can run.  Their return type should already be routed elsewhere, and their arguments are already bound.

```
llQueue<std::function<void()>> workQueue;
```

now there remains a technical issue.  `std::function<void()>` requires that it be copyable; bit the easy way to wire the callableWork to a future leaves you with a non-copyable packaged task.

There are a few ways around this.  The first is to shove the packaged task into a shared ptr then store that in a function.  The second is noting that `packaged_task<T()>` is a move only callable with signature `void()`, which can be stored in a `packaged_task<void()>`.

So we come full circle.

```
struct ThreadPool {
  template<class F, class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>>
  std::future<R> submitWork(F f){
    auto task=std::packaged_task<R()>(std::move(f));
    auto r=task.get_future();
    workQueue.push_back(std::packaged_task<void()>(std::move(task)));
    return r;
  }
  std::vector<std::packaged_task<void()>> workQueue;
  // or:
  //llQueue<std::packaged_task<void()>> workQueue;
  // with changes to how things are enqueued
};
```

and as a bonus it deduces the return type for you.  [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0714c7b50299794).

I believe I have seen at least one C++ compiler that screwed up and made packaged tasks require copyable contents.  So the shared ptr containing function may be your backup plan.

Comment: Sorry i posted pseudo-code and obviously missed alot, thank you. I have one question, when the void() packaged task is eventually executed in one of the worker threads isn't it going to return void? How do i get that return value back out of the void packaged_task (fulfilling the future is then trivial).

Comment: @steph the furure is wired up in the submitWork function.  There is nothing to do once it is executed.

Comment: oooh i see. I for some reason thought you had to explicity fulfill the future later, sweet that's even cleaner than i thought

Comment: I've hit a slight snag. It appears that the implicit conversion on enqueue isn't working and im not sure why. If instead i make the assignment explicit by adding the following line it works: ```std::packaged_task<void()> voidTask(std::move(task));``` why must i explicitly construct a void packaged_task?

Comment: @StephenEckels Sure.  It turns out packaged task ctor-from-function is explicit.  So, fix it?